# How to use typedef in header file cpp

Tags: c++, oop, g++, header-files

I have created a new type using typedef and a struct. I want to export that type as a module.

I have the following cpp header file:

```cpp
//header.h
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Vector;
#endif

#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H
class Plane {
    public: 
        //this works
        Vector n;
        //this does not work
        Plane(Vector P1, Vector P2, Vector);
};
#endif
```

This is the module file:

```cpp
//module.cpp
#include header.h
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Vector;

class Plane {
    public: 
        Vector n;
        Plane(Vector P1, Vector P2, Vector P3) {...}
};
```

And in this file, I create an object of the class Plane calling the constructor:

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include header.h
float distance = 10;

int main() {
    Vector P1 = { 0, 0, 11.5 };
    Vector P2 = { 0, distance, 10 };
    Vector P3 = { distance, distance, 5 };

    Plane E(P1, P2, P3);
    return 0;
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
undefined reference to `Plane::Plane(Vector, Vector, Vector)'
```

What causes this error and how can I resolve it?

I use the following command to compile:

```
g++ main.cpp header.h
```

Comment: @Lala5th I've included the compile command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Lala5th When I build it using g++ main.cpp calculations.cpp I get the error ```previous definition of 'class Plane'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be copying the `Plane` class's declaration, while an include is enough, so change your `module.cpp` file into something like:

```
#include "header.h"

Plane::Plane(Vector P1, Vector P2, Vector P3)
{
}
```

> **Note** that above does **define** what the header does **declare**, in C and C++, we can separate the declaration from definition
> (I mean, method or function's `{}` body).